# find_if using Lambda to return index instead of value of vector

Tags: c++

I am looking to return the index of a vector where it's value is greater than an input value. I am able to return the value with the code below. How can I return the index instead?

```
auto res = std::find_if(height.begin() + i + 1, height.end(),
    [&height, i](int x) {           
    return height[x] >= height[i];
});

cout << "The next highest index in the array is " << *res << endl;
```

This is the input vector:

```
vector<int> height = { 1,2,6,2,5,4,8,3,7 };
```

Comment: `std::distance(height.begin(), res)`

Comment: Or `res - height.begin()`.

Comment: BTW, you should check that `res != height.end()` before deferencing it to avoid UB (and think which value you expect for index in that case).

Comment: @Jarod42, I do check in the later if statement

if (res != height.end() && higher_index < height.size())

Comment: @paolo thanks it works. but I have another issue. the find_if is not returning what I expect on the second iteration of my for loop. I will open another question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided in the comments:

```cpp
std::distance(height.begin(), res)
```

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) this operation is _linear_. Thus potentially turning the code into O(n^2)